# What would we call Monero users in Esperanto?

Tags: monero-terminology, esperanto

What would we call Monero users in Esperanto? I have seen the term "moneranoj" mentioned on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6mneuj/15000_moneranoj/). Is this correct? Does there exist a word for a single Monero user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'j' at the end is for the plural, so a single user should be a "monerano,"  I think.  I've just picked up a little Esperanto in recent weeks.

Thanks to

https://www.reddit.com/user/lethos3

Answer (score 1):

List of Monero-related Esperanto words [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3exy7t/esperanto_corner/).